# How can I programmatically bulk delete redirect entities based on their status code?

Tags: 8, redirection

I have a list of 3089 301 redirects URLs and want to delete them programmatically from the database.

E.g *List of source URLs*

/about/test/2013/page_61732.html
/about/test/additional/branches/page_38678.html
/about/test/additional/branches/page_38678.html
/about/test/additional/branches/page_38678.html
......

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to delete all redirects with a status code of 301. That could be done like this:

```
$ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('redirect')
   ->condition('status_code', '301')
   ->execute();

$entities = Redirect::loadMultiple($ids);

\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('redirect')->delete($entities);
```

If you only want to delete redirects that have a certain source URL, you should be able to add

```
->condition('redirect_source__path', $sources, 'IN')
```

to your query.

Comment: Not sure if 3089 entities shouldn't better be processed in a batch process? 

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
        use Drupal\redirect\Entity\Redirect;
        
        //list of all source urls
        $newInputs = [
            '/about/*****/2013/page_61732.html',
            '/about/*****/additional/branches/page_38678.html',
            '/about/*****/additional/branches/winners/page_38681.html',
            '/about/*****/additional/development/winners/page_38703.html',
             .....................
        ];

    
        foreach ($newInputs as $input) {
                 $sourceUrl = trim($input);
    
                 $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('redirect')->getQuery(); 
                 $redirects = $query->condition('redirect_source.path', substr($sourceUrl, 1))
                           ->execute();
        
                 $storageHandler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('redirect');
                 $entities = $storageHandler->loadMultiple($redirects);
        
                 foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            
                         //get redirect source path
                          $sourceRedirectUrl = $entity->getSourceUrl();
            
                          if ($sourceRedirectUrl == $sourceUrl)
                             {
                               $entity->delete();
                       
                              }
                           elseif (urldecode($sourceRedirectUrl) == urldecode($sourceUrl))
                              {
                                $entity->delete();
                               }
                           else
                               {
                                print 'Error !! Bad Url in the record';
    
                                Print "Source Url from list : ".urldecode($sourceUrl)." \n Source Redirect Url " .urldecode($sourceRedirectUrl). "\n"; 
                                }
            
                }
          }
    
      print 'There were ' . $done . ' redirects deleted.' . "\n";
```

Comment: Better use [loadByProperties](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x) instead of that nested double looping